# Configure different websites in Apache

Tags: networking, apache2, websites

I have two directories in `/var/www` called `acollida` and `segona`. I have an `index.php` file in both of the directories, as well.

What’s more, in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/` I have two archives:

`acollida.com.conf`, with:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin xxx
    ServerName acollida.com
    ServerAlias www.acollida.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/acollida
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

And a file called `segona.com.conf` with:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin xxx
    ServerName segona.com
    ServerAlias www.segona.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/segona    
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I've also enabled the sites with this command:

```
a2ensite
```

I’ve disabled the `000-default` site as well as restarting the server.

And in `/etc/hosts` file I have:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   ubuntu01

192.168.10.17 segona.com
192.168.10.17 acollida.com
```

Well, when I put `aocollida.com` or `segona.com` on the server it works, but when I use it while on another computer in the net, using the name of the server (`SLTUBUNTU01`) or the IP (`192.168.10.17`) it always shows the `acollida.com` site. For example:

Going to `SLTUBUNTU01` or `192.168.10.17` shows `acollida.com`
And when I put `SLTUBUNTU01/acollida.com` or `SLTUBUNTU01/segona.com`, it doesn’t work.

Does anyone know how I could solve this problem?

---

Ubuntu version: Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS

---

`/etc/network` file:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto ens160

# DHCP not needed
# iface ens160 inet dhcp
iface ens160 inet static
address 192.168.10.17
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.10.0
broadcast 192.168.10.255
gateway 192.168.10.15
dns-nameservers 192.168.10.1 192.168.10.6
```

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

everything looks fine on your server but when you try access to web server form another computer you need a dns server to try change website name to ip address. like your server that add two line in `/etc/hosts` add ip address and web site name in `/etc/hosts` in client side not only server .