# Access multiple websites configured in apache in localhost

Tags: networking, server, ssh, apache2, localhost

On my *Raspberry Pi 3+* I followed the instructions to [install and configure apache](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-and-configure-apache#3-creating-your-own-website), and now I can view:

1. Default apache configuration on `localhost`, and
2. GCI webpage on `gci.example.com`

### Configuration Files

#### `gci.conf`

```bsh
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cat /etc/apache2/sites-available/gci.conf
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        ServerName gci.example.com

        ServerAdmin  webmaster@gci.example.com
        ServerAlias  www.gci.example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/gci/public_html/

        <Directory /var/www/gci/public_html/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride all
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

#### `hosts`

```bsh
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1             localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1         ip6-allnodes
ff02::2         ip6-allrouters

127.0.1.1       raspberrypi
127.0.0.1       www.gci.example.com
```

### Access both `localhost` and `gci.example.com`

I have connected to my Pi using SSH using PuTTY, and I have added the tunneling as below:
[image]

Now, when I go to `localhost` I can see the default apache page which is configured, but I am not able to find the `gci` webpage.

I've tried to use a different port, but it was not working. I am new to apache, so might have done something wrong?

**I want to access multiple websites configured under `/var/www/` of my Pi from my Windows machine using PuTTY, or other tools (if required).**

These links [link-1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/265300/how-do-i-setup-name-based-virtual-hosts-using-ubuntu-12-04), [link-2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/896407/configure-different-websites-in-apache) suggested using DNS settings, but I don't understand how to do that.

**`ifconfig`**

```bsh
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ifconfig
eth0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether b8:27:eb:40:c3:ea  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 33  bytes 15256 (14.8 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 33  bytes 15256 (14.8 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.102  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 fe80::1de9:48e4:f9ed:2850  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether b8:27:eb:15:96:bf  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1124  bytes 243059 (237.3 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 755  bytes 128636 (125.6 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Comment: Why are you tunneling through port 80. Why not SSH to default port 22? And why SSH to localhost?

Comment: Using SSH on Port 22, but tunneling apache port 80 (I thought that was the default one).

Comment: Just to be clear... do you want to access the directories and files under `/var/www/` or do you want to tunnel the HTTP requests from web-browser on one machine to a web-server on another machine via SSH?

Comment: want to access HTTP requests from web-browser on one machine to a web-server on another machine via SSH

Comment: Then do not use localhost in the tunnel destination... use the IP of the other machine instead.

Comment: On using the IP I'm able to view the default apache page, which comes from `default-0000.conf` file I believe. I also want to access the `gci` web page that I have created...

Comment: www.gci.example.com will not resolve using public DNS servers... You need to configure some sort of host-name / domain-name overriding / remapping / forwarding in your router.